# Calling a method from every class that implements an interface

Tags: c#, class, methods, interface, game-engine

I'm working on a game engine. Now assume we have a Game class:

```
    using System;

    using OpenTK;
    using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
    using System.Drawing;
    using static OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL;

    namespace Test2
    {
        class Game : GameWindow
        {
            public Game(int width, int height)
                :base(width, height)
            {

            }
            protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnLoad(e);
            }
            protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnUpdateFrame(e);
            }
            protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnRenderFrame(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

And we have a medium in which to call a method for every frame.
Now assume the person creating a game, creates a file called ball_behaviour script:

```
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;

    namespace Test2.Project.Behaviour
    {
        class Ball
        {
            public void Update()
            {

            }
            public void init()
            {
                A2D.Background = Color.CornflowerBlue;
            }
            public void preInit()
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

And assume there are other files like it, which have the methods Update, and init. How can I call these methods from protected override void OnRenderFrame for example, in every class that's registered under Test2.Project.Behaiviour namespace? Thank you so much in advanced.

EDIT:The GameWindow class comes from OpenTK, which is the API I'm using to interface c# with OpenGL.

EDIT #2: Kind of like the way Unity does it.

Comment: Use a DI framework like MEF, Unity, or autofac

Comment: You could require the classes inherit from a common base class that tracks the classes, or you could use Reflection to locate all classes in the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a virtual void that you than override which would be easier and faster to implement,have done this thing yesterday

Comment: please provide code sample and more details